# How to change the name of the button on filepicker in meteor?

Tags: coffeescript, meteor, filepicker

I use filepicker to upload the images but by default it gives the name "Pick File" which I couldn't change it. I have used 
`button(type="filepicker", id="upload_widget") UPLOAD`but it doesnot change the name to upload.
Please help me out, how could I change the name ? I am using jade-handlebars and coffeescript in meteor.
Thank You in advance.!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use your own button, attach an event handler and then call filepicker.pick via javascript manually.

To my mind this is the preferred way of using filepicker because the automatic filepicker button generation is buggy in Meteor anyway, which must have something to do with a conflict in the way Meteor and filepicker handle the DOM under the hood.